# finish() called when email intent not selected or back is pressed

Tags: android

So I have a button that brings up an intent:

```
case R.id.email:
        Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String uriText;

        uriText = getResources().getString(R.string.mailto)
                + "?subject=Subject" + "&body=";
        uriText = uriText.replace(" ", "%20");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

        send.setData(uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send,
                getResources().getString(R.string.send_mail)));
        break;
```

So the options for different e-mail apps are shown. When I press off of this intent (ie. not selecting anything), the activity containing this popup is finished. Why is this?

Comment: to clarify, is your activity getting finished?

Comment: Yes it is, the activity is having a finish() call